# "git push tag" command giving access denied

Tags: tags, gitlab-ci

After a successful pipeline, we push a tag using command git(“push”, “origin”, newtag).
The problem is i am using a group level access token with role as maintainer. It works fine as long as i do not remove a member named A from our project.
If i remove Member A from our project then it stops working and gives error. How can group level access token be associated with it? I created the token. I tried using my own personal access token but same behaviour i.e. if i remove that user A then it does not work.